# Sprite Kit. SKSpriteNode not appearing on iPhone 4 but appears on 4S

Tags: sprite, sprite-kit, iphone-4, skspritenode

I am creating a game using sprite kit. Everything works and looks great on all devices (including 4S) except on the iPhone 4.

All devices are running on the latest iOS 7.

Everything else seems to be working fine on the iPhone 4. Its just the background image sprite. That appears black instead.

My thoughts are that it is there but positioned off screen.

here is my code for adding in the background...

```
//bgImage
    bgImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BG_1"];
    bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    bgImage.zPosition = 0;
    [self addChild:bgImage];
```

Question 1: As far as screens go, aren't the iPhone 4 and 4S the same? same size and both retina?

Question 2: Does anyone know of any reason, why this is happening?

Comment: hi i really don't know why you have this behavior but you can try to set the size like this 
inline `CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)`

Comment: Have you tried using a different image?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. So I think I have figured out what was happening. The Background image is fine. The problem was that I have another set of images on top of the background creating a parallax scroll effect. But it looks like the iPhone 4 processor couldn't render the images (as they have a lot of transparency) fast enough and instead was filling in the node with black (hiding the BG). I am  currently testing out this theory..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum texture size is 2048x2048 for iphone 4 and 4096x4096 for iphone 4s and above. If image size is too large it will show black image instead. I used to had this problem before and after I resized the image problem solved. Hope this will fix yours too.